# Partial View - Get html that would be render

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, ejs

**Context:** 
I've created a GET request in my route folder that sends html. It will be used for a ajax request:

```
router.get(url, function(){
  res.send("<p>Some Text</p>");
})
```

My idea/doubt/problem is the following, is it possible to use a partial view in order to generate the html that I want and send it?

I have a partial view with the code i need, that's used in the main rendering, and it's frustrating to edit the code in two different sections.

Comment: Can you post the partial view you want to use?

Comment: Already found my way sir. You can check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way:

```
res.render(view, function(err, html){
  if(!err){
    res.send(html);
  }
});
```

If the callback function is used, the default behaviour of rendering the page is canceled.